Error when trying to install NvChad on Ubuntu 24.10
When I try to download Nvchad for my neovim on Ubuntu 24.10 i get this error:
Error detected while processing /home/laptop/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/laptop/.config/nvim/init.lua:7: atte
mpt to index field 'uv' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
/home/laptop/.config/nvim/init.lua:7: in main chunk

I have followed the Nvchad doc and got this error and I can't install Nvchad, I have tried all solutions I found but it is not fixed.
